# eager loading e queries costumizadas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Esta pergunta é um *follow up* [desta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921277/limit-on-inner-join-per-parent/49921488) e [desta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917399/eloquent-hasone-and-a-big-table-doesnt-limit-in-the-query/49917933?noredirect=1#comment86852407_49917933). Mas vou tentar torná-las independentes.

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas, `weathers`:

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| id     | temp  | id_freg |
+--------+-------+---------+
|    337 | 12.36 |       1 |
|   3556 | 11.46 |       2 |
|   6775 |  9.30 |       3 |
|  10210 |  8.55 |       1 |
|  13429 |  9.69 |       2 |
```

`freguesias`:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Cabeção   |
|  2 | Pavia     |
|  3 | Brotas    |
|  4 | Mora      |
```

Cada freguesia pertence a um concelho:

County Model (concelho):

```
...
public function freguesias() {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Freguesia::class, 'id_county');
}
...
```

Freguesia Model:

```
...
public function county() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\County::class, 'id_county');
}

public function current_weather() {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Current_Weather::class, 'id_freg')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
...
```

Estou a fazer um eager loading desta maneira:

```
...
$county = County::with(['freguesias' => function($q) {
    $q->with(['current_weather']);
}])->select(['id'])->findOrfail(request()->id);
...
```

O que eu quero é os ultimos `weathers` para cada freguesia que pertence ao `County`, ou seja, por outras palavras o tempo current, mais recente de cada freguesia, para isso podemos seguir-nos pelo `weathers.id`.

Eu [já tenho o SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921277/limit-on-inner-join-per-parent/49921488) que gostaria de usar para ir buscar os as ultimas linhas inseridas para um conjunto de freguesias:

```
select w.* 
from weathers w
where w.id_freg in (X, Y, ...) and
     w.id = (select max(w2.id) 
     from weathers w2 
     where w2.id_freg = w.id_freg
     );
```

Nota: Esta é uma tabela com muitos dados (mais de 4 mihlões de linhas, e mais a cada hora que passa)

A solução `hasOne(\App\Weather::class, ...)` no Model Freguesia não não é eficaz (performance muito má) pois não limita na própria query, `... LIMIT 1`, na minha opinião deveria fazer mas não faz.

Comment: O relacionamento não seria belongsTo com HasMany? 1 weathers tem 1 freguesia e 1 freguesia pode estar em varios weathers! tem coisa erradas nas relações e no seu modo de interpretar, ou coisa se precisa utilizar aquela SQL pode usar direto `DB::select` [vide documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries)

Comment: Mas gostava de fazer daquela query uma relação @VirgilioNovic, para que consiga fazer eager loading da relação na mesma. Entretanto resolvi com  uma resposta no SO EN, em baixo a solução.

Answer (score 0):

[Consegui resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925564/translate-sql-raw-query-into-eloquent-relationship/49931546#49931546) graças a um colega no SO EN:

No meu Model Freguesia:

```
...
public function current_weather() {
    $f_key = 'id_freg';
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, $f_key)
        ->where('id', function($query) use ($f_key) {
            $query->selectRaw('max(id)')
                ->from('weathers as w2')
                ->where('w2.' .$f_key, DB::raw('weathers.' .$f_key));
        });
}
....
```

Assim consigo na mesma:

```
...
$county = County::with(['freguesias' => function($q) {
    $q->with(['current_weather']);
}])->select(['id'])->findOrfail(request()->id);
...
```

O meu problema era deparar-me com o facto de a relação hasOne não limitar o resultado na própria query, extrai todas as linhas e depois retorna a primeira, isso é horrível para a performance quando se tem alguns milhões de linhas numa tabela (weathers neste caso). REF: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: "Comentário": *O meu problema era deparar-me com o fato de a relação `hasOne` não limitar o resultado na própria `query`, extrai todas as linhas e depois retorna a primeira, isso é horrível para a performance quando se tem alguns milhões de linhas numa tabela(weathers neste caso).* -> **isso é verdade ele não limita a quantidade (por exemplo colocar** `limit 1` **)**, porque, ele acredita logo de cara que a relação e `1` para `1` e não `1` para `N`, porque você faz uma busca no `max(id)` da sua tabela aonde o `primary key` da outra tabela repete nela então não é hasOne! é hasMany! cont

Comment: continuando, ou seja, tem um problema de configuração nas suas relações com a maneira como o framework ORM `Eloquent` trabalha. Pra você ter uma idéia geral não precisa aquele monte de código era só escrever: `return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, $f_key)->limit(1)->orderByRaw('id desc');` acredito que só isso resolveria, mesmo sendo uma relação diferente do que deveria ser, então resolveu seu problema, mas, eu gostaria de dizer que a sua percepção está um pouco equivocada.

Comment: continuando. a minha intenção é ajudar a entender, e não fique preocupado, não vou negativar, porque de certo modo chegou a alguma solução que traz o resultado que precisa, mas, nem sempre o que funciona é o correto.